# containsValues checking Dictionary<type, object> c#

Tags: c#

with ECPoint class :

```
public class ECPoint
{
    private BigInteger p, x, y;

    public BigInteger P
    {
        get { return p; }
        set { p = value; }
    }

    public BigInteger X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public BigInteger Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public ECPoint(BigInteger p, BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
    {
        this.p = p;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

I have a dictionary in C#:

```
Dictionary<BigInteger, ECPoint> hashTable = new Dictionary<BigInteger, ECPoint>();
```

and an object of ECPoint Class :

```
ECPoint gamma = new ECPoint(p, Qx, Qy);
```

p,Qx,Qy are numerical values

And I did this test :

```
if (hashTable.ContainsValue(gamma))
{

    BigInteger j = -1;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<BigInteger, ECPoint> s in hashTable)
       {
         if (s.Value.X==gamma.X && s.Value.Y==gamma.Y)
            {
               j = s.Key;
               return m*j;

            }

       }
}
```

The problem is this test has never given a true value, it is always false, so how to check if the dictionary hashTable contain the values of an object?. Someone can help me, thanks in advance, and I apologize for my English.

Comment: You should override [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) in ECPoint.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like you haven't - which means it'll be using reference equality. Note that using automatically implemented properties would reduce the size of your `ECPoint` implementation massively, too...

Comment: Why you ever need `ContainsValue` (linear search) just to do another linear search?

Comment: can someone clarify, I am a beginner in c #;

Answer (score 1):

You can use FirstOrDefault() linq function to check and get value from `hashTable` so you don't have to iterate with foreach.

Your code will be like this:

```
 var data = hashTable.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value.X == gamma.X && a.Value.Y == gamma.Y);

    if(data != null){
       return data.Key * m;
    }
```

Comment: Well, it might work but doesn't explain why Op's `if (hashTable.ContainsValue(gamma))` is never entered. It's a workaround.

Comment: You right. But the code is much simpler. And I think is really what Yldir try to achieve.

Comment: @Ygalbel The problem is in the test "if (hashTable.ContainsValue (gamma))"

Answer (score 0):

You could either implement Equal and GetHashCode or turn ECPoint into a structure so the compare no longer uses a reference comparison.

Comment: you can clarify more sir, I am a beginner in c #